# Background service not running on a fully managed device in Android Management API

Tags: android, policy, background-service, kiosk, android-management-api

We maintain our own enterprise in Android Management Api.
All the devices we maintain are fully managed devices.
In one policy we installed a private app with the installType "Force_installed".
This app needs constant time synchronization with the Micro SD card.

However when the device goes to sleep the synchronisation stops.
That is why we implemented a background keep-alive service that is started from that same app.

We can see the service is running when we swipe down the notification area.
On a MDM managed Android device, it shows a red circle and after getting back from sleepmode,
we can see the time synchronization stopped.

On a normal Android device, it shows a gray circle. And the synchronization was running the whole time.

What can we do to make it run the whole time on a MDM managed Android device.
We suspect it has to do with a policy setting, but we are not sure which one.
And we are not sure how to implement it.

[Here is the service running on a normal Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0RKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can try granting permissions like autoStart, background, or similar permissions on your app through policy

```js
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.myapp.test",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "permissionGrants": [
        {
          "permission": " android.permission.READ_CALENDAR",
          "policy": "GRANT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

references:-
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#PermissionPolicy

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the keep-alive service application is always running, you can grant permission to the keep-alive service application.

Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#PermissionGrant) for additional information.

I have also tried to recreate the scenario using a different keep-alive application by granting background permission and the app runs the whole time.

Sample Code:

```
    "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.nstudio.keepalive",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "permissionGrants": [
        {
          "permission": "android.permission_group.CALENDAR",
          "policy": "GRANT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```